# Copying worksheet as new workbook keeping format, dropdown list etc

Tags: excel, vba

I have workbook which has worksheets with data contains colour, drop down (with drop down selection the cell changes its colour) etc. formatting. I been trying to create copy of particular worksheet and send it using easy right click and create copy to new workbook which creates the copy but doesn't carry the cell colour which are based on the text value. So far I have tried to do it using different VB codes which come up with same result- creates new workbook and paste data but without formatting. I have tried using the code below:

```
Sub CopySheetToNewWorkbook1()

    Dim wname As String

    wname = ActiveCell.Value

    Sheets(wname).Cells.Copy

    Set nbook = Workbooks.Add(1)
    With nbook.Sheets(1)
    .Cells.PasteSpecial xlValues
    .Cells.PasteSpecial xlFormats
    End With

    Range("a:l").EntireColumn.AutoFit
End Sub
```

another attempt:

```
Sub CopySheetToNewWorkbook2()
    Dim wname As String

    wname = ActiveCell.Value
    Sheets(wname).Activate
    Range("a1:l25").Copy
    Set nbook = Workbooks.Add(1)
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAllUsingSourceTheme, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False
    Range("a:l").EntireColumn.AutoFit
End Sub
```

I thought this one will work as saving the workbook with preserve all the formatting but again it turned as no help. (Also it was able to create the copy but not getting saved, came up with error msg "method Save As for object workbook failed") :

```
Sub CopySheetToNewWorkbook3()

    Dim wname As String

    wname = ActiveCell.Value
    Sheets(wname).Copy

    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs "C:\Data:\Roster.xlsx", FileFormat:=51
End Sub
```

The last attempt before I gave up and decided to ask for help (on this one I didn't quite know how do I refer to past in to new workbook - absolute failure:

```
Sub CopySheetToNewWorkbook4()
    Dim wname As String
    wname = ActiveCell.Value

    Set nbook = Workbooks.Add
    Sheets(wname).Copy before:=Workbook.nbook.seehts(1)
    With nbook.Sheets(1).UsedRange
    .Value = .Value
    End With
End Sub
```

I hope I can get pointed to right direction as I have attempt all possible help I could find with no success till now.

Comment: I want to add that with all above attempts, it does copy the cell colour for some of the cells but not all of  them.

Comment: (a) I assume in all these attempts, the value of the active cell at the time the macro is invoked was the name of the sheet to be copied?  (b) In `CopySheetToNewWorkbook4` the bit saying `Workbook.nbook.seehts(1)` should be `nbook.Sheets(1)` to make any sense, but `Sheets(wname)` won't exist in the new workbook so the copy won't work. (c) In `CopySheetToNewWorkbook3` you have an invalid filename - paths cannot contain a `:` - that is reserved for the separator between drive and path.

Comment: @YowE3K yes, I have the list of worksheets names and all the worksheets exist in workbook which is referred by the worksheet name list (which is activecell.value).

Comment: @YowE3K thanks for all the inputs, I rectified all of them but I am at the same point.. do you want to signal any move to right direction that I can try to make sure the cell formation get copied over into new workbook?

Answer (score 0):

This will:

- copy a sheet to a new workbook
- save the new workbook
- close the new workbook
- control then returns to the original workbook

In a standard module:

```
Sub Macro1()
Sheets("Sheet1").Copy
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs _
    Filename:="C:\Users\garys\Desktop\newname.xlsm", _
    FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled, _
    CreateBackup:=False
ActiveWorkbook.Close
End Sub
```

Comment: thank you for this, but its getting me the same output - its creating new workbook with all data but not copying across the colours in cell (which are based on text selected by drop down.. in case this information can be any help)